# gdal.driver.create is removing another file in the directory

Tags: python-2.7, gdal

I've been working with gdal in python for a few years, and the past few days I've found what I suspect may be a bug in the gdal driver's Create command. I'm working with Landsat imagery, and have tried the below code on a few scenes with the same results each time. In certain situations, when I call create, it deletes another file in the directory (always the MTL file).

```
import gdal

path = '.../LC80110112013243LGN00/' #path to where ever your landsat scene is

outfile = path+path[-22:-1]+'_B5_test.tif'
#outfile = path + 'TestB5.tif'

infile = path+path[-22:-1]+'_B5.tif'

infile_open = gdal.Open(infile)
infile_array = infile_open.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()  

dtype=gdal.GDT_Float32

outfile = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(outfile, infile_array.shape[1], infile_array.shape[0], 1, dtype)

infile_open = None
outfile = None
infile_array = None
```

If I use the first outfile name, which creates a filename matching the rest of the Landsat band files, and the file "outfile" already exists, it is replaced (expected behavior) and the met file is deleted (unexpected behavior). If I use the second outfile name, which does not match the Landsat band filename format, when I run the code if "outfile" already exists it simply replaces the old file (expected behavior). I have not been able to find any other reference to this happening. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I can't replicate this with `gdal.VersionInfo() ==  '2010100'`. 

When using the `_B5_test.tif` outfile a `...._B5_test.IMD` file is created but the `.MTL` file is not removed.  When using the `TestB5.tif` outfile there is no metadata file created.

Comment: Thanks @LoganByers. Did you try running the code more than once with the ..._B5_test.tif file already existing? On the first run (where _B5_test.tif doesn't exist), my .MTL file stays and the test.tif file is created, but if I run the code a second time (such that _B5_test.tif already exists and should be replaced), the .MTL file still disappears. I don't think I've ever seen an .IMD file created, which is interesting. I'm using `gdal.VersionInfo() == '2010300'` on a Mac through spyder started from within an anaconda environment. I'm happy to provide versions of the above if that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly!

GDAL Version: GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01

Paltform: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Out of the situation so:

*`. . .
if os.path.exists(outputFileName):
   os.remove(outputFileName)
dst_ds = driver.Create(outputFileName, width, height, bands_value, gdal.GDT_Float32)
. . .`*

Comment: I'm so glad somebody else has replicated this problem! os.remove is definitely a great workaround (upvoted your answer), it's just an odd issue to have to begin with. Please share if you end up finding out anything more about what's causing this.